# Should I avoid a switching frequency close to my target SPI or CAN frequency?

Tags: power-supply, buck, emc, signal-integrity, switching-regulator

I have a kind of an open-ended question.

If I'm designing a board with a buck converter and have picked out my peripherals, and say for example I want to run my CAN FD interface at 1MHz baud and maybe a SPI signal at 1MHz, and I am now looking at power supply design.

I am looking at a buck switching regulator which has a switching frequency at 1.4MHz.  Is there any big EMI issues with having the switching frequency so close to the frequency of my other signals running through the board?  Should I aim at either a higher or lower frequency?

Pretty open-ended question, but I never really thought of it until I ran into it.

Comment: This question is too open. If you have no coupling between the switching freq. and SPI, then it does not matter. But if you have a coupling, it might be best to keep the frequencies apart as far as possible. So what could be a good advice here?

Comment: @StefanWyss Hmm, maybe I can expand.  The power from the buck converter would be used on the power plane to power both a microcontroller and peripheral devices.  Expected stackup is sig - gnd - power - sig.

Comment: How much filter attenuation do you have inside that power distribution?

Answer (score 2):

If the regulator were that bad it'd screw up the board operation no matter what.

If you had a radio in there, then having a regulator switching at the RF frequency or a sub-multiple of it could be an issue (as could having a microprocessor clock close to a frequency you care about).  But CAN and SPI aren't going to notice anything that won't generally make the whole board unable to function.